# Excel list made available according to the value of another excel list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

[image]

What I am trying to achieve:

I want the DeviceType column to be a pull down list according to whatever the value is in Site field.

`If Site =DEEZW,DEEZWTEC,DELPZ,DELPZFAB,DESHE,DEZUF,DEZUFTEC`
The Pulldown list should be `Server,Client,Network,WLAN-Client-Corporate,WLAN-Client-Fabrik,WLAN-Client`
For any other site it should read Server,Client,Network,WLAN-Client

At the moment, it is easy as all DeviceTypes have been the same and I have only to reference them using a NAME.

I can't seem to get my head around this, although I suspect there is a relatively easy way to do it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for [cascading drop down lists](https://superuser.com/questions/714702/how-do-you-make-a-set-of-cascading-dropdown-lists-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I am still none the wiser
If Site = 'DEEZW' then give me list "DeviceTypeA'.  This I can do with an Indirect.

I am trying to achieve following

If Site (Field G2) = item from SiteListA, then give me List DeviceTypeA in field I2
If Site (Field G2) = item from SiteListb, then give me List DeviceTypeB in field I2

DeviceTypes can be referenced with Names.  Easy.     I just cannot work out how to program this in data validation.

I have read the link you gave, but none the wiser

Answer (score 0):

=IF(COUNTIF(CAMPUSLocation;G2);DEVTYPESPAG;DEVTYPESNONPAG) in data validation table

It works, not quite sure how, but it does what I need

Comment: The `IF` performs its logic test on the return value of `IFCOUNT`. Excel automatically converts number values to Boolean in this case. So when the value returned by `IFCOUNT` is any number other than zero, Excel converts the value to `TRUE` but zero is converted to `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Now it makes sense