# Creating custom data validation lists from formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I am creating a quick database involving multiple vendors from multiple countries. On 1 worksheet (titled 'Vendors List'), there is a list of countries, vendors, Vendor codes and Territory codes. On the 2nd worksheet ('Database'), there is a much larger database which includes many more columns but includes all of those from the 'Vendors list. What I want is when I type in the country in 'Database', I want the Vendors column to automatically create a list so that only the Vendors in that country can be selected.

Is this possible using just the in-built formulas in Excel?

[Example of 'Vendors List'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkGAA.png)
[Example of 'Database'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbe2Z.png)

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a [cascading dropdown list](https://superuser.com/questions/714702/how-do-you-make-a-set-of-cascading-dropdown-lists-in-excel)

Comment: The database *tag* seems inapplicable here. A spreadsheet is not a database, and calling something in a spreadsheet a database doesn't change that.

Comment: The first question is what version of Excel are you using.   Try looking at the FILTER function. You might need to compounded FILTER Functions, but it might accomplish what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a "drop-down" list that will restrict the choice of vendors to those associated with an already selected country in the adjacent cell then here's some Excel functions to help you.

- [`MATCH`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
- [`COUNTIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)
- [`OFFSET`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)

In the Vendor's List" the `MATCH` function can be used to find the position of the first occurrence of a specific country within the Country column. The `COUNTIF` function can be used to find the number of times that the same specific country appears in the Country column. With these two numbers, the `OFFSET` function can then be used to identify a range containing the list of vendors in the Vendors column which correspond to the specific country.

For example, if the Vendors List is in say range `Vendors!A1:D5` and the specific country is in say cell `Data!A2`, then the range containing the corresponding vendors would be provided by:

=`OFFSET(Vendors!$B$1,MATCH(Data!A2,Vendors!$A$1:$A$5,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(Vendors!$A$1:$A$5,Data!A2),1)`

For reasons explained later, a more general and more useful version of this formula is:

=`OFFSET(Vendors!$B$1,MATCH(Data!A2,Vendors!A:A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF(Vendors!A:A,Data!A2),1)`

There is an important requirement here: in the Vendor's List the rows must be arranged by Country - all the Brazil rows must appear consecutively and similarly for any other Country appearing in the Vendor's list. If this condition is not met, the range of vendors produced by the formulas above will not be correct.

The easiest way to ensure the requirement is met is to sort the Vendor's List by Country.

Data validation can be applied to cell `Data!B2` by selecting the cell and clicking the "Data Validation" button from the ribbon under the Data menu item. A Data Validation dialog will appear. Choose List in the Allow field and paste the more general `OFFSET()` formula above into the Source field with the Data Validation dialog.

If the data validation is successfully implemented, whenever `Data!B2` is selected as the active cell, a drop-down arrow will appear to its right and clicking the arrow will produce a list of Vendors matching to the Country shown in cell `Data!A2`.

Copying cell `Data!B2` downwards to the remaining data rows in the main "database", will associate all the cells in the column with the same data validation - the drop-down list for cell `Data!B3` will be based on the country in `Data!A3`, `Data!B4`'s list will be based on `Data!A4`, etc. A drop-down arrow will still appear if the corresponding cell in `A` is empty but will not display a drop-down list. The copy/paste operation can be undertaken before any value has been entered into cell `Data!B2`

**Notes:**

1. Use of the more general OFFSET() formula allows the Vendor's List to be extended by adding rows to without changing the data validation applied to the cells in `Data!B`. (Note the extended list may require sorting by country to meet the requirement that countries must be grouped together in the Vendor's List). If the less general version is used, the data validation formulas would require updating each time the Vendor's List was extended.
2. In a real database, in-built facilities enforce integrity of the data. For example, even though the drop-down lists ensure that the vendors in column `Data!B` are consistent with the countries in `Data!A` when the vendor values are first entered onto the worksheet, there is nothing to  prevent a country in `Data!A` being subsequently changed and this will break the consistency between it and the Vendor value in showing in the same row in `Data!B`.
3. In addition, Country names appear in both the main "database" and the Vendor's List. A real database would ensure no mismatch of countries between the two. Mismatches can be flagged in Excel by adding extra columns but are much more difficult to prevent. The same remark applies for Vendor names.